# Rails: rake aborted due to an already existing table but can't remove it

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rake

I have created a model named Categorie in my Rails App.
Due to a mistake, I needed to remove the model.

I ran

```
rails d model Categorie
```

Which removed my existing model.

I have forgotten to run `rails g migration DropTable` at that moment.

But then, I needed to re-create the Categorie model so i ran :

```
rails g model Categorie name:string
```

But when i want to run `rake db:migrate` i get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: Table 'categories' already exists: CREATE TABLE `categories` ...
```

After that, I've tried to drop the table to redo all the process but it doesn't work, the table is still in `schema.rb`

I know it's not recommended to do it manually from the file that's why i'd like to know if someone would know something about it. I know it's an idiot mistake but now i don't know how to fix this.

Here is how i've tried to drop the table:

```
rails g migration DropCategories

def change
  drop_table :categories
end

rake db:migrate
```

I think there is a problem with removing the table because here is the output when i migrate the database:

```
== 20170509123739 CreateCategories: migrating =================================
-- create_table(:categories)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: Table 'categories' already exists: CREATE TABLE `categories` (`id` int(11) auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, `name` varchar(255), `created_at` datetime NOT NULL, `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Rails seems to CREATE a table and not DELETE the one i want.

Comment: How did you try to drop the table? The error message is happening because the table is still in your MySQL database, not because it's in `schema.rb`. If you use a MySQL client to drop the table, then your migration should succeed no matter what is in `schema.rb`.

Comment: @Brian i did rails g migration DropCategories and then i modified the migration file with drop_table :categories

Comment: You can try to rollback ( rake db:rollback ), and then change your migration files so that you only have one file that creates the table. 
N.B: a rollback rolls the schema back to the previous version.

Comment: @OthmaneElKesri I've already done that but nothing new happened

Comment: rollback 3 times, and then you edit your migration files so that you only have one file that create the categories table

Answer (score 0):

You can simply drop the table if it exists in your new migration:

```
def change
  reversible do |dir|
    dir.up do
      drop_table :categories if table_exists? :categories # pre rails 5
      drop_table :categories, if_exists: true # rails 5 and onwards
    end
  end

  # put the rest of your migration here:
  create_table :categories do |t|
    t.string :name

    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

The `reversible` bit ensures that the custom table deletion code is only executed when running the migration normally, and is ignored whenever you do a `rollback`.

Comment: I've juste done something way easier. I used a MySql client for Mac called SequelPro. I've deleted the table with it and know everything works perfectly ! Thanks for contributing anyway !

Comment: Your question related specifically to how to solve this without doing it manually. You've just done exactly the opposite of what you were looking for. My answer still stands and would have worked for you.

Comment: I didn't say anything like that. I just asked for a way to solve my problem which was removing a table from my database in any way ! But thanks for you answer once again i'm sure it will be helpful for someone else or even me some day !

Comment: I'm not usually one to pick at something like this, but you did actually say "I know it's not recommended to do it manually from the file that's why i'd like to know if someone would know something about it".

Comment: ok i understand i was actually meaning doing it manually from schema.rb

Comment: I know that. Maybe my question wasn't really clear. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to fix the issue

1. in your migration file comment the code in 'change' method

   ```
   def change
     create_table :categories do |t|
       #t.string :name
       #t.timestamps
     end
   end
   ```
2. run rake db:migrate command
3. uncomment the code in 'change' method

   def change
     create_table :categories do |t|
       t.string :name
       t.timestamps
    end
4. Now run rake db:migrate
5. Now your migrations get restored to normal and you can continue what you need